# Modifying an object in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to learn some OpenGL via [this tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Intro%20What%20is%20OpenGL.html).

My question is regarding these lines of code:

```
glObjectParameteri(GL_MODIFY, GL_OBJECT_AN_INTEGER, 5);
glObjectParameterf(GL_MODIFY, GL_OBJECT_A_FLOAT, 0.4f);
glObjectParameters(GL_MODIFY, GL_OBJECT_A_STRING, "Some String");
```

So far, an OpenGL object was made `Object`, bound to the target `GL_MODIFY` and now these codes are supposed to modify the contents of the object. My question is, what is the point of the second parameter in each of these functions? (`GL_OBJECT_AN_INTEGER`, `GL_OBJECT_A_FLOAT`, and `GL_OBJECT_A_STRING`) It seems that the function `glObjectParameteri` would be specific to integers since the function has an `i` at the end.

Comment: Be advised, that those functions are not part of OpenGL at all. The part you've been reading is about how the OpenGL API is designed in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the parameter, not its type (example puts the type in the name to show what `i`, `f` and `s` suffixes mean). There can be more than one parameter of each type, and I believe psychic abilities haven't made their way into OpenGL standard yet.

Comment: Yeah thanks, this makes sense, along with the other example on that page.